# MVC - two text box with the same parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Orders1", "Track", FormMethod.Post))
{
         @Html.TextBox("order")<br />
         @Html.TextBox("order")
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Hello how can i use two text box and pass value to the same parameter? The first textbox work but the other textbox doesn't.

```
   public ActionResult Orders1(IEnumerable<int> order)
        {
             var query = from   a in context.CM_Checkout_Details
                        where  a.CheckoutDetails_ID == order // my error
                        select a;


            return View(query);
        }

    }
```

Comment: i want to display all of the matching ids for CheckoutDetails_ID and order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple solution would be to change your parameter from `int` to `IEnumerable<int>`

```
public ActionResult Orders1(IEnumerable<int> orders)
{

}
```

Comment: hey thank for the reply. I edit my controller and get an error in the where clause line ... how can i convert my order parameter since its a IEnumerable??? thank you in advance